# OpenGL 2D textures jittering/pulsing

Tags: c++, opengl, game-engine, texture2d, freeimage

I am currently working on a 2D game engine called Regula. I have just finished a batch rendering system that renders 2D textures submitted to it in batches of 32. In testing it's capability of rendering over 32 textures I found that the textures rendered seem to pulse or jitter. The effect is unwanted and highly annoying. It seems to happen more when the camera is moving. Additionally, occasionally the textures will have small artifacts on them if the camera is in a specific position. I've been trying to rectify the issue for some time now but have not been able to succeed.

[Here is a rather boring video illustrating the effect](https://youtu.be/VP3dQdNhZ3o).

You can find all the source code of the engine at Regula's GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/MurderMantis612/Regula).
The files of intrest are:

- Regula\Regula\Inc\Regula\Graphics\BatchRenderer.h
- Regula\Regula\Src\Graphics\BatchRenderer.cpp
- Regula\RegulaTestBench\Inc\Game.h
- Regula\RegulaTestBench\Src\Game.cpp
- Also maybe the Camera2D class in Regula\Graphics
- Potentiallt the ShaderManager class
- or the shaders in Regula\RegulaTestBench\Resources\Shaders\DefaultSprteShader.vert/frag

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Possibly you have floating point underflow or cancellation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Most people don't or forget to enable V-sync. Try enabling glfwSwapInterval(1) when you create window.

Comment: Hey, I tried enabling V-Sync but unfortunately the problem persists. Sorry for the delay been a bit busy, just graduated high school.